# Inner join table with multiple rows/results grab the first one . Error : #1055

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT p.product_id , p.product_slug , p.product_name , c.category_slug 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_category_relations pcr ON pcr.relations_product_id = p.product_id 
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = pcr.relations_category_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY p.product_id
```

Error:

> #1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'c.category_slug' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

One product can have multiple relations/categories `INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = pcr.relations_category_id`, I only want to grab the first.

How can I achieve this with one query?

Example:

[image: uery]

Comment: Its MySQL - sorry,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation function on the non-product columns, presumably `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_slug, p.product_name,
       group_concat(c.category_slug) as category_slugs
FROM products p JOIN
     product_category_relations pcr
     ON pcr.relations_product_id = p.product_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.category_id = pcr.relations_category_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY p.product_id ;
```

In general, the `SELECT` columns must match the `GROUP BY` keys.  In fact, that mismatch is causing your error.

In this query, the mismatch is allowed specifically because (presumably) `product_id` is the primary key of `products`.  When you aggregate by the primary key (or any unique key), then you can select other columns.  You can slo be explicit, though:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_slug, p.product_name,
       group_concat(c.category_slug) as category_slugs
FROM products p JOIN
     product_category_relations pcr
     ON pcr.relations_product_id = p.product_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.category_id = pcr.relations_category_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.product_slug, p.product_name 
ORDER BY p.product_id ;
```

Comment: That works, but the categories are comma separated .  Its there a way to grab only the first result ?

Comment: I understood, this works : ```SELECT p.product_id, p.product_slug, p.product_name,
       group_concat(c.category_slug) as category_slugs
FROM products p JOIN
     product_category_relations pcr
     ON pcr.relations_product_id = p.product_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.category_id = pcr.relations_category_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.product_slug, p.product_name , c.category_slug
ORDER BY p.product_id```